# How to get my program to reset and add a continue prompt that will restart automatically restart program

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, pycharm

I created a one-rep max calculator for powerlifting. Everything runs fine but I want it to end with a restart prompt in case the user wanted to calculate another lift. (Keep in mind I am very new to coding and Python).

I have played around with different variables but I am struggling with properly declaring the function and then running the loop.

```py
Welcome= 'Hello and welcome to one rep max calculator, Please follow the prompt below'
print (Welcome)

reps= int(input('Rep Count?'))

initial_weight= int(input('Weight lifted?'))

bench_max=(.0333 * reps + 1) * initial_weight
print (bench_max)

reply= 'y'

question= 'Do you want another calculation?'
def yes_or_no(reply):
    reply= 'y'

    while "the answer is invalid":
        reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
        if reply[0] == 'y':
            return True
        if reply[0] == 'n':
            return False

yes_or_no(reply)
```

There is no error message, but the program doesn't restart, regardless of whether I hit yes or no.

Comment: can you include the code where you use this yes_or_no function?

Comment: Please format it properly.  Formatting and indentation in particular are very important in Python.

Comment: `while "the answer is invalid":` is always true. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @ZacharyOldham uhh I thought I was calling it right at the end but i guess not lol. Essentially, I just want a "do you want to run the program again?" prompt after the calculation is printed

Answer (score 0):

This will make the prompt ask until you get a valid answer.

```py
def yes_or_no():
    reply = ''
    while reply not in ['y', 'n']:
        reply = input(question+' (y/n): ').lower().strip()
        if reply == 'y':
            return True
        if reply == 'n':
            return False
```

If you want the program to exit when you say no, you can do the following:

```py
import sys
sys.exit() # replace the 'return False' above with this statement
```

Then to get it to run continuously until you tell it to exit, just put the code you want to repeat in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the issue Johnny Mopp pointed out, you can do

```py
def yes_or_no(reply):
    reply= 'y'

    while "the answer is invalid":
        reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
        if reply[0] == 'y':
            return True
        if reply[0] == 'n':
            return False

while True:
    Welcome= 'Hello and welcome to one rep max calculator, Please follow the prompt below'
    print (Welcome)

    reps= int(input('Rep Count?'))

    initial_weight= int(input('Weight lifted?'))

    bench_max=(.0333 * reps + 1) * initial_weight
    print (bench_max)

    reply= 'y'

    question= 'Do you want another calculation?'

    if (not yes_or_no(reply)):
        break
```

Comment: ahh now its running very smoothly. sort of a noob question, but is that typical to start the program as a function like that right from the beginning.

Comment: I typically lay out my programs as follows: imports, global variables, functions, code, but it is really up to you. One thing you don't want is function definitions in the middle of code, though